# Issue regarding Sublime Text 2 console input (Python 2)

Tags: python, console

I've been getting back into Python and usually I use IDLE but I like sublime better so I've been playing around with it and I realize that the console doesn't accept input. I checked a few threads on here and people were saying I had to install the "SublimeREPL" extension via package control. Well I've done just that and I still get the following error everytime I run the code:

```
Enter your name here: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carsonclark/Documents/Python Projects/Drills1.py", line 5, in <module>
    name = raw_input('Enter your name here: ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

Perhaps there's some kind of setting I need to change or something? I'm on a Mac (Mavericks) and I'd really appreciate anybody's help. Thanks for reading.

Edit:

How can I run the file to the left in such a way that I can enter input.. this is what I have so far..

http://i.gyazo.com/d720c6b7e9c2e71fdc22588e4db0bbd1.png

Comment: Are you actually *running* SublimeREPL (Tools > sublimerepl > python)?

Comment: Hello, when I click preferences > package settings > SublimeREPL > Settings > Default it just brings up a a new tab with some code.. but I'm not sure if I have to do anything with that code.. or if it should be working automatically. 

Thanks

Comment: Im an idiot, I just noticed it was located under the "Tools" option when you mentioned it.. Thanks but I'm still unsure as to how I can run my programs with this extension